# Keeping a grid withing the 1st page css

Tags: html, css

So I've put this big grid container inside a flex container that's the same size of the browser, now my problem is inside this flex there's also my navbar which takes only 10 view height of the screen, then there's my grid which always takes more than the rest of the flex container and it goes over the screen height. Even though I fix it to only 90 view height, it's content would still go over that height. What can I actually do to make it keep into that 90 view height?

HTML and CSS:

```
    <div class="mainpage">
    <section class="nav">
       <div class="logo "
       </div>
       <ul class="navbar">
       </ul>
    </section>
    <section class="container">

        <div class="description pageone">
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
.mainpage{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url("./images/background.jpg");
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: top center;
 
}
.nav{
    position: sticky;
    top:0;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    overflow: hidden;
    display:flex;  
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-content: center;


}
.nav *{
    line-height: 10vh;
    height: 10vh;
}
.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    display: flex;

}
.pageone{
    display: grid;
    height: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows:2% 1fr 1fr 1fr 2%;
    grid-template-areas:
    ". . . . . . ."
    ". hero hero . . . ."
    ". hero hero . . . ."
    ". hero hero . text text ."
    ". . . . . . ."
    ;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

So I found the problem by myself. Since the flex was set to wrap, all the content from the navbar go over the 10 view height occupying more than 10% of the view height, that's why when I rezise my browser to a smaller size all the content from the grid would go over the screen height.

```
/*From this*/
.nav{
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
/*To this*/
.nav{
flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```